# How to prevent object properties from being overwritten

Tags: javascript, typescript, loops

I'm building a function that creates a nested object with dynamic properties which has the year and month as keys.

```js
const sixMonthSummary = {};
// This will get data for the latest 6 months
for (let i = 0; i <= 6; i++) {
  const currentDate = new Date();
  const [, month, year] = new Date(
    currentDate.setMonth(currentDate.getMonth() - i)
  )

    .toLocaleDateString("en-SG")
    .split("/");

  sixMonthSummary[year] = {
    [month]: {
      rent: "",
      income: "",
      expenses: "",
    },
  };
}

console.log(sixMonthSummary)
```

The output only captures the last index and the first index instead

```json
"2020": {
  "07": {
      "rent": "",
      "income": "",
      "expenses": ""
  }
},
"2021": {
  "01": {
      "rent": "",
      "income": "",
      "expenses": ""
  }
}
```

How do I make sure that the other months are not missed out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are overwriting the complete object-key at

> sixMonthSummary[year] = {}

try to insert the existing object with a **spread-operator** to include all prev months.

```js
const sixMonthSummary = {};
// This will get data for the latest 6 months
for (let i = 0; i <= 6; i++) {
  const currentDate = new Date();
  const [, month, year] = new Date(
    currentDate.setMonth(currentDate.getMonth() - i)
  )

    .toLocaleDateString("en-SG")
    .split("/");

  sixMonthSummary[year] = {
    ...sixMonthSummary[year],
    [month]: {
      rent: "",
      income: "",
      expenses: "",
    },
  };
}

console.log(sixMonthSummary)
```

Comment: Brilliant solution!

Answer (score 1):

It's because you're resetting the year key each iteration of the loop. Try something like

```
if(!sixMonthSummary[year]) {
 sixMonthSummary[year] = {};
}

sixMonthSummary[year][month] = {
 rent: "",
 income: "",
 expenses: "",
};
```